# Не выводится содержимое arraylist за пределами запроса

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, arraylist, android-vksdk

У меня есть фрагмент, который содержит запрос на вывод информации о группах пользователя.

Проблема в том, что если вывожу `arrayid` за пределами запроса, то выводится пустой `arrayid`. А если в запросе то все хорошо. В чем может быть причина? Спасибо!

```
public class fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment;
    private View view;
    ArrayList<String> arrayid = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT,container,false);
    VKRequest vkRequest = VKApi.groups().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, "name"));
    vkRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            System.out.println(response.responseString);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.json.get("response");
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
                System.out.println("ssshsh"+jsonArray);
                for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject name  = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                    arrayid.add(name.getString("id"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //если вывожу тут, то все работает 
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arrayid));


            }
        });
    //если вывожу тут то выводится пустой arrayid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина в том, что в случае вывода `arrayid` на консоль за пределами коллбэка `onComplete(...)`, этот `arrayid` еще не заполнен данными.

Вы выполняете **асинхронный** запрос, в котором заполняете данными `arrayid`. Но на момент вывода `arrayid` запрос еще не выполнился, следовательно `arrayid` будет пустым.

Comment: как я могу исправить это ?

Comment: @DonaldRump, Выводите данные после выполнения запроса. Т.е. в коллбэке `onComplete(...)`.

Comment: @DonaldRump а зачем вам исправлять это? Выводите в `onComplete` и не мучайтесь, запрос же должен сформироваться, чтобы ваш `arrayid` заполнился

Comment: ну например, если я хочу использовать этот arrayid в других методах и запросах. Есть еще варианты ?

Comment: @DonaldRump, После выполнения запроса Вы можете запустить другой метод, который будет что-то дальше делать.

Comment: а как узнать что запрос выполнен ?

Comment: @DonaldRump, После выполнения запроса будет вызван метод `onComplete(...)`.

Comment: То есть, мне нужно проверить вызван ли метод ? Если да, то можете подсказать как это сделать ?

Comment: @DonaldRump, Нет. Просто в конце метода `onComplete(...)` вызывайте другой метод.

Comment: Как я не мог додуматься. Спасибо большое !!